# MooTools: grab to bottom right

Tags: javascript, mootools

To go straight to the point:

I have a container div that receives a number of inline-block elements. Depending on the number of elements the container has to receive, these elements are sized consequently to follow those rules:

```
for(i=0; i<elements.length;i++){
     switch (number of elements){
          case 1: elements[i].width=100%; break;
          case 2: elements[i].width=50%; break;
          case 3: elements[i].width=33.3%; break;
          case 4:if(i<3){elements[i].width=33.3%;}else{elements[i].width=100%;}break;
          case 5:if(i<3){elements[i].width=33.3%;}else{elements[i].width=50%;}break;
          case 6:elements[i].width=33.3%;break;
     }
}
```

And, for now, the container **grabs** them at the top (MooTools .grab(element, 'top') method).

So I have this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq4T0.png

But what I want is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTrTp.png

So, to be very much concise, I want the elements to be added to the container on the **bottom right** and push the other elements **up** the container, which is why I cannot simply use .grab(element, 'bottom').

I've been turning that in my head for two days and looked every relevant MooTools doc but it seems I cannot solve this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

er, depends what you do, but seeing as you have failed to post a DOM, or your inject code, here's a rundown of what's available.

you have 3 hooks into moving/changing parent nodes:

## inject

`element.inject(target, 'bottom|top|after|before')`

## adopt

`parent.adopt(element)`

## grab

`parent.grab(element, 'bottom|top|after|before')`

they amount to the same thing. you have failed to show how the actual injection happens but your loop is from el#1 to last one, hence each consecutive element will - by default - go to the bottom.

you'd do that simply via:

`element.inject(cellElement)` - by default that goes to the bottom, so it will do 1,2,3,4,5,6 in order of the loop. Add 'top' instead as argument to reverse it or if you did a `while(lengthVar--) {}` you can reverse it. I'd recommend using `Array.each` to loop the elements (or `Elements.each`, as it were - it can also give you a handle on the index, if you need it)

you can also use `element.inject(cell.getLast(), "before")` or follow whatever index you deem fit. post more code or better yet, create a http://jsfiddle.net example and we can look at sorting it out.

Comment: Cheers a lots. I can't really share the code as it is intellectual property of my company so I gave a pseudo-code loop just to give the idea. I thought it would be enough. But I guess I won't be able to go around the element.inject(cell.getLast(), "before") solution which I would have preferred to avoid. But I think you are right, it is the only way. Thank you again!

Comment: `element.inject(cell, "top");` ?